# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) after using react Router. Error pointing to ReactDOM.render in index.js

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, router, react-router-dom, react-dom

i am working using BrowserRouter.Router from react-router-dom in my App.js to link all my pages.
When after using react router, i get this error in the browser.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4F3I.png)

As you can see, the error is pointing to reactDOM.render in my index.js. I don't understand why that should be an issue if i use react router in App.js.

This is that my App.js looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Navbar from './components/Navbar/index';
import Footer from './components/Footer/index';
//pages
import Home from "./components/Pages/Home";
// import About from "./components/Pages/About";
import Portfolio from "./components/Pages/Portfolio";
import Contact from "./components/Pages/Contact";

import './App.css';

function App() {
  return(
    <Router>
      <Navbar/>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route exact path="/about" component={Home}/>
        <Route exact path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio}/>
        <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
      <Footer/>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is what my index.js file looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
// Learn more about service workers: 
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

I'm not sure what the issue is, could someone explain to me why reactDOM.render is affected by using Router in App.js. It looks like i've imported everything properly. I need a second pair of eyes. PLEASE HELP! lol Thank you

CodeSandbox located:

> https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-colden-0c73r?file=/src/App.js

Comment: you should have a minimal reproducible example on codesandbox

Comment: @hgb123 I have added a codesandbox link